# jq - print newlines while processing rows from an array

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have a json like this:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "hello"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "world"    
    }
  ]
}
```

I could do this:

```
$ jq -r '.records[] | "id: \(.id) name: \(.name)"' afile.json
id: 1 name: hello
id: 2 name: world
```

How can I insert new lines so that I could get this:

```
id: 1
name: hello

id: 2
name: world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) combined with [`join("\n\n")`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) to insert an `\n` between each iteration. This way there won't be a trailing newline:

```
jq -rj '.records | map("id: \(.id)\nname: \(.name)") | join("\n\n")' input.json
```

```
id: 1
name: hello

id: 2
name: world
```

---

> ###### `--raw-output` / `-r`:
>
> With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

> ###### `--join-output` / `-j`:
>
> Like `-r` but jq won't print a newline after each output.

Comment: Thanks! And this is weird because I tried adding `\n`s yesterday and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways would be simply to add `\n` to the end of the string specification.

If the extra newline at the end is unwanted, you could, for example, use `sed '$d'` to remove it.

Comment: And then use `head -n -1` to remove the trailing newline after the last line.